# How to hide invocation context while debugging quarkus app

Tags: java, debugging, quarkus, invocation

I'm debugging a quarkus based app with VSCode. The call stack contains all the machinery that's under the hood, like:

```
io.quarkus.arc.impl.AroundInvokeInvocationContext.proceed(AroundInvokeInvocationContext.java:53)
io.quarkus.arc.runtime.devconsole.InvocationInterceptor.proceed(InvocationInterceptor.java:62)
io.quarkus.arc.runtime.devconsole.InvocationInterceptor.monitor(InvocationInterceptor.java:49)
io.quarkus.arc.runtime.devconsole.InvocationInterceptor_Bean.intercept(Unknown Source)
io.quarkus.arc.impl.InterceptorInvocation.invoke(InterceptorInvocation.java:41)
io.quarkus.arc.impl.AroundInvokeInvocationContext.perform(AroundInvokeInvocationContext.java:40)
```

I'd prefer the hood closed! Also, when stepping into/out of methods, the debugger takes me to this code I'm not interesting in. I'm not debugging Quarkus, but my app!

Is there a setting somewhere to hide this stuff?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to step into Quarkus code while debugging, you should configure your IDE to skip `io.quarkus.*` methods. For example, in IntelliJ IDEA, you'd go into Settings / Build, Execution, Deployment / Debugger / Stepping, enable *Do not step into the classes*, and add the filter.

You can also turn off CDI monitoring by setting `quarkus.arc.dev-mode.monitoring-enabled=false`. That will get rid of `io.quarkus.arc.runtime.devconsole.InvocationInterceptor` completely.